# Return inserted entity in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to have inserted data in stored procedure, because of of sql injection I use `prepare` and `execute` statement.

what should I've done to have the inserted data

> following code is only a part of user table

```sql
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `UserCreate`
(
    IN `@Name`      VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
    SET @Query = CONCAT
    (
        'INSERT INTO
            User
            (
                Name      
            VALUES
            ('
                , '\'' , `@Name` , '\','
            ')'
    );

    PREPARE Statement FROM @Query;
    EXECUTE Statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE Statement;

END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

- I use Binary uuid for having more security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That's not using "prepare" to do the escaping.  Put the IN parameter in the EXECUTE.
- Please don't name parameters with `@` -- it is too confusing with @variables.  I like to prefix in args with `_`.
- A UUID is 36 characters; The binary equivalent is `BINARY(16)`.  Your `VARCHAR(32)` does not agree with "I use Binary uuid for having more security".

Comment: Thanks for your help and great response, It helped me a lot, sorry for my delay to make it verified answer